# TYPO3 - Custom page types not showing in menu

Tags: typo3, fluid

in my TYPO3 7.5 project I have created some custom page types by registering them in ext_tables.php as described further [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/PageTypes/Index.html)

I can select those page types in the backend, no errors, all good. Also checking for a certain page-type via  statements in the frontend works fine.

Now I want to create a menu of those (sub-)page trees. The TypoScript solution looks like this and works fine:

```
lib.tourTeasers = HMENU
lib.tourTeasers {

special = directory

wrap = <section class="row">|</section>

1 = TMENU
1 {
    wrap = <div class="col-sm-12">|</div>

    expAll = 1

    NO {

        doNotLinkIt = 1
        linkWrap = <h2 style="text-align:right">Kategorie: |</h2>

    }
}

2 = TMENU
2{

    expAll = 1

    NO{

        doNotLinkIt = 1
        linkWrap = <h3>Tourtyp: |</h3>
    }
}

3 = TMENU
3{
    NO{

        doNotLinkIt = 1
        linkWrap = <h4>|</h4>

        after.cObject = COA
        after.cObject {

            stdWrap.dataWrap = <div class="row teaser">|</div>

            10 = FILES
            10 {
                references {
                    table = pages
                    fieldName = media
                }

                renderObj=IMAGE
                renderObj{
                    file{
                        width=300c
                        height=150c
                        #maxW=257c
                        #maxH=150c
                        import.data= file:current:publicUrl
                    }

                    altText.data = file:current:title
                    #altText.field=abstract
                    #titleText.field=nav_title
                    #stdWrap.dataWrap = |</a>

                    stdWrap.dataWrap(
                        <a href="index.php?id={field:uid}" title="Tour {field:title} ansehen">
                            <div class="col-sm-4 teaser__image">|</div>
                        </a>
                    )

                    params = class="img-responsive"
                }
            }

            30 = TEXT
            30.field = abstract // bodytext
            30.crop = 250
            30.wrap = <div class="col-sm-8 teaser__description"><p>|</p>

            40 = TEXT
            40.value = Ansehen
            40.typolink.parameter.field = uid
            40.typolink.ATagParams = class="btn"
            40.wrap = <div class="button teaser__cta">|</div></div>

        }


    }
}
}
```

My problem is:

If I use the very Fluid Viewhelper that is intended to render exacly the same

```
            <v:page.menu.directory pages="{page_uid}" as="tours" expandAll="true">
            <f:for each="{tours}" as="tour">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <v:page.resources.fal table="pages" field="media" uid="{tour.uid}" as="images">
                            <f:for each="{images}" as="image">
                                <f:image src="{image.url}" alt="{image.alternative} {image.name}" title="{image.title}" class="img-responsive"/>
                            </f:for>
                        </v:page.resources.fal>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <h3>{tour.title}</h3>
                        {tour.abstract}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </f:for>
        </v:page.menu.directory>
```

{page_uid} being the parent page, nothing is displayed.

If I change some of the sub-pages' doktype back to "default" they are displayed in the rendered menu.

any idea as to why this is? Am i missing a certain argument in the viewhelper? i also tried to set the allowed doktypes in the viewhelper but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: AFAIK the menu generation code does only work on the hard coded doctype values.

Comment: Please show me the value you use for "allowed doktypes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the reponses, indeed it had to do with the doktype, is I didn't include the "new" ones for both the parent pages AND their sub-pages. Works now, solved. Fluid really rocks